# runit - unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, daemon, init, daemontools, runit

I'm trying to figure out why runit will not boot or give me the status for the managed applications. Running on Ubuntu 12.04.

I created /service, /etc/sv/myapp (with a run script, a config file, a log folder and a run script inside of it). I create a symlink from /service/ to /etc/sv/myapp

When I run

```
sudo sv s /service/*
```

I get the following error message:

```
warning: /service/myapp: unable to open supervice/ok: file does not exist
```

Some of my Googling revealed that supposedly rebooting the svscan service might fix this, but killing it and running svscanboot didn't make a difference.

Any suggestions? Am I missing a step here somewhere?

Comment: Had exactly this on Debian 10. The answer below to install `runit-systemd` fixed it for me—`runit` has no **systemd** unit file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that, at least on Ubuntu 12.04, runit services symlinks should be placed under /etc/service, not /service as per the [Arch guide on Runit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Runit)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I deleted the **lock** and **pid** from the service configuration after stopping the service:

```
# stops the service 
sv down serviceName

# deletes the 'pid' and 'lock' files
find -L /etc/service/serviceName -type f \( -name "pid" -o -name "lock" \) -delete

# starts the service
sv up serviceName

# verify service status
sv s serviceName
```

It took me a while to find the solution, so I hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also learned that we can't add the log service after the service is installed to /etc/service. No amount of restarting works. Therefore, we can also stop the service, remove the symlink from /etc/service, and re-symlink it.

Comment: Didn't know that

Answer (score 3):

If you are running ubuntu 18.04 or higher and getting the following error

> unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist

or if the runsvdir is not showing up in "grep" output then please **runit-systemd** package by running the following command

```
sudo apt install runit-systemd
```

For ubuntu 18.04 all the above specified answers did not worked for me. I have then found this solution from another askubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046836/how-to-properly-setup-runit-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I hope this helps

Comment: This is the answer. Worked on Debian 10 too. Added a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo runsv /service/run/ &
```

Then

```
sudo sv  start /service/run/
```

or

```
sudo sv  up /service/run/
```

Answer (score 0):

Runit also has trouble starting when a service is symlinked to a directory that is mounted on a different filesystem via LVM. For example,

```
$ readlink -f /etc/service/my-service
/opt/my-service

$ mount
...
/dev/mapper/lvm--local-opt on /opt type ext4 (...)

$ sv once my-service
warning: my-service: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

Possible solutions:

- Unmount the filesystem from LVM
  `umount /opt; lvremove /dev/mapper/lvm--local-opt`
- Move the runit service to a better location
  `update-service --remove /opt/my-service; mv /opt/my-service /etc/sv; update-service --add /etc/sv/my-service`