# warning: couchdb: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist - Runit

Tags: linux, centos7, couchdb, runit

I was trying to run couchdb with runit, and I encountered the error above. Even [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/520741/runit-unable-to-open-supervise-ok-file-does-not-exist), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/609780/trying-to-log-with-runit-only-returns-unable-to-open-supervise-ok) and many others didn't help me in knowing what the problem is.

Here was what I did to produce the problem. Runit and couchdb were installed fresh.

I am running CentOS 7.

Step 1: Make sure that couchdb command is correct:

```
#exec /usr/local/bin/couchdb

Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.                                                         
Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.                                                                
[info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://0.0.0.0:5984/
```

Step 2: Make a folders. Here is what my folder structure like:

```
/
|--etc
    |--sv
        |--couchdb
    |--service
```

Step 3: Inside `/etc/sv/`, I create a file name `run` with the following script inside:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                     
exec /usr/local/bin/couchdb
```

Step 4: Activate it by linking the process directory:

```
ln -s /etc/sv/couchdb /etc/service/couchdb
```

Step 5: Try to run it:

```
#sv start couchdb                                                                
warning: couchdb: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

All the search results point to the same sort of steps that need taking. I followed all the instructions I could find and I got stuck here.

Comment: Why aren't you using a systemd unit?

Comment: I've been trying to work out with systemd unit but there is no clear tutorial on how it works. I had tried many options before I tried runit.

Comment: It's so easy that a tutorial is hardly necessary. Just see the documentation if you run into any trouble. Or start with a systemd unit for couchdb that someone else has already written (such as [this one](https://github.com/CleverCloud/systemd-services/blob/master/couchdb.service)).

Answer (score 0):

#### `runit` needs `runit-systemd` for CouchDB control

I had **exactly the same issue on Debian 10** and - as with a lot of CouchDB setup - the answer isn't easy to find.

However, a [post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061997) pointed out that “the `runit` package does not provide a systemd unit file” —this is provided by `runit-systemd`, so…

`‌sudo aptitude install runit-systemd` did the job.

**Before:**

```sh
sudo sv status couchdb
warning: couchdb: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

**After:**

```sh
sudo sv status couchdb
down: couchdb: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 24238) 122s
```